# Storing objects in an array, my values keep changing within my array

Tags: java, arrays, object

So I have a while loop which stores all of my variables, but my problem is that whenever the program loops it changes the values of the object in the previous array. So employeeArray is filled with all objects of the same values rather than storing the previous value and creating a new one. I am reading text from a .csv file.  Can somebody please explain to me how to store my Employee objects without them changing each loop? Let me know if you need any clarification I know I probably missed some information somebody trying to help me may need.  Anyways my code is below, I have 3 different classes but Im just going to put the Employee and EmpQuery class on here. I believe the problem is with my variables in the Employee class. PLEASE HELP ME, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class EmpQuery extends Employee {

    public static void fillArrayObjects(Scanner s, Employee[] e){

        //VARIABLES
        String sNextLine;
        int counter = 0;
        int parsedString;

        String employeeID;
        String employeeName;
        String employeeDepartment;
        String employeeStartDate;
        int employeeEarnings;

        //DECLARE ARRAY TO HOLD EMPLOYEE OBJECTS
        Employee employeeArray[] = new Employee [50];//50 records I believe

        while(s.hasNext()){

            //SCANNER AND SEPARATE STRING VALUE IN LINE
            sNextLine = s.nextLine(); 

            String[] tempSplit = sNextLine.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", -1);

            //REMOVE EVERYTHING EXPCEPT NUMBERS [4]
            tempSplit[4] = tempSplit[4].replace(",","");
            tempSplit[4] = tempSplit[4].replace("$","");
            tempSplit[4] = tempSplit[4].replace("\"", "");
            tempSplit[4] = tempSplit[4].replace(".00","");
            parsedString = Integer.parseInt(tempSplit[4]);

            //STORE TEMP SPLITS IN NEW VARIABLES
            employeeID = tempSplit[0];
            employeeName = tempSplit[1];
            employeeDepartment = tempSplit[2];
            employeeStartDate = tempSplit[3];
            employeeEarnings = parsedString;

            //CALLING FROM EMPLOYEE CLASS
            Employee.enterData(employeeID, employeeName, employeeDepartment, employeeStartDate, employeeEarnings);

            //STORE EACH NEW EMPLOYEE IN employeeArray
            Employee i = new Employee(employeeID, employeeName, employeeDepartment, employeeStartDate, employeeEarnings);
            employeeArray[counter] = i;

            //TESTS
            System.out.println(counter + "  " +  Employee.getEarnings(employeeArray[0]));//employee[1] keep changing every loop            

            //INCREMENT COUNTER
            counter++;

        }

        System.out.println(Employee.getEarnings(employeeArray[12]));
        System.out.println(Employee.getID(employeeArray[3]));

    }

*************************************NEW CLASS******************************
```

package employeedb;

/**
 *
 * @author Daniel
 */
public class Employee {

```
//VARIABLES***************************************************************************************************
public String empID;
public String empName;
public String department;
public String startDate;
public int earnings;

Employee newGuys;



//EMPLOYEE*********************************************************************************************************
public Employee(){

    empID = "";
    empName = "";
    department = "";
    startDate = "";
    earnings = 0;
}


public Employee(String iD, String name, String employeeDepartment, String startingDate, int salary){

    empID = iD;
    empName = name;
    department = employeeDepartment;
    startDate = startingDate;
    earnings = salary;        

}

public Employee(String iD, String name){

    empID = iD;
    empName = name;

}



//ENTER DATA*******************************************************************************************************
public void enterData(){

    empID = "";
    empName = "";
    department = "";
    startDate = "";
    earnings = 0;

}


//ENTER DATA
public void enterData(String iD, String name){

    empID = iD;
    empName = name;
    department = "";
    startDate = "";
    earnings = 0;

}


//ENTER DATA
public void enterData(String iD, String name, String employeeDepartment, String startingDate, int salary){

    empID = iD;
    empName = name;
    department = employeeDepartment;
    startDate = startingDate;
    earnings = salary;

}



//VIEW SPECIFIC FIELD****************************************************************************************************
public void viewEmployeeID(Employee variable){

    System.out.println(empID);

}


public void viewEmployeeName(Employee variable){

    System.out.println(empName);

}


public void viewDepartment(Employee variable){

    System.out.println(department);

}


public void viewStartDate(Employee variable){

    System.out.println(startDate);

}


public void viewEarnings(Employee variable){

    System.out.println(earnings);

}



//VIEW DATA**********************************************************************************************************
public void viewAllData(){

    empID = "";
    empName = "";
    department = "";
    startDate = "";
    earnings = 0;

    System.out.println("Employee ID:    " + empID);
    System.out.println("Employee name:    " + empName);
    System.out.println("Employee department:    " + department);
    System.out.println("Employee start date:    " + startDate);
    System.out.println("Employee earnings:    $" + earnings);
    System.out.println("");

}


//VIEW DATA
public void viewData(String iD, String name, String employeeDepartment, String startingDate, int salary){

    empID = iD;
    empName = name;
    department = employeeDepartment;
    startDate = startingDate;
    earnings = salary;

    System.out.println("Employee ID:    " + empID);
    System.out.println("Employee name:  " + empName);
    System.out.println("Employee department:    " + department);
    System.out.println("Employee start date:    " + startDate);
    System.out.println("Employee earnings:  $" + earnings);
    System.out.println("");

}



//RETURN DATA*********************************************************************************************************

//GET ID
public String getID(Employee variable){//void

    return empID;

}


//GET NAME
public String getName(Employee variable){

    return empName;

}


//GET DEPARTMENT
public String getDepartment(Employee variable){

    return department;

}


//GET START DATE
public String getStartDate(Employee Variable){

    return startDate;

}


//GET EARNINGS
public int getEarnings(Employee Variable){

    return earnings;

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you set the variables in `Employee` as static, that means they are shared in every instance of the class.
They should not be static so every object has their own.

Comment: Okay thanks that helps but now I get this error: "Uncompilable source code - non-static variable empID cannot be referenced from a static context", whenever I try to use the methods in the Employee class, even when i make the methods no longer static. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seem you're still using static methods, maybe it's the call to Employee.enterData (that does not make sense, you should remove it). Otherwise you should show your updated code.

Comment: I updated my code and removed all the static parts of the method. Do I need to be using 'this.empID, this.empName' etc? My only problem with the non static part is that now I cant call my methods from other classes I get the error code:  "Uncompilable source code - non-static variable empID cannot be referenced from a static context" everytime.

Comment: To call non static methods you just have to create an object with `new` and call the methods with it. It's really basic stuff, you should check a basic Java tutorial. As I told in my previous comment `Employee.enterData` is a static call (you're not calling it with an object) so you should remove it.

Comment: Ahh perfect, thank you! One last question haha, any idea how I would go about displaying (with a System.out.println(......)) a specific value for the array. Like for example I would like to check the value of empID in employeeArray[4]? Thanks for your time

Comment: supposing you have this class: `class Employee { private String empID; .... public String getEmpID() { return empID; }` you get empID this way: `Employee employee = new Employee(...); .... String myEmpID = employee.getEmpID();`

Comment: for array: `Employee[] employees = new Employee()[50]; .... employees[4] = new Employee(...); .... String myEmpID = employees[4].getEmpID();`

Comment: Thank you so much. This is my first time ever using stackOverflow and I can see it will be a very useful tool in the future